# How do I write well-covered test cases using Mocha and Istanbul?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js, chai, istanbul

I am trying to write a unit test case for a Mongoose model function using chai & Mocha.

**Model function**

```
function getDetails(parameter, fn) {
    Model.findOne({
            parameter: parameter
        })
        .lean()
        .exec(function(err, document) {
            if (err) {
                return fn(err, null);
            }
            return fn(err, document);
        });
};
```

**Unit test case**

```
describe('→ Database model functions.', function() {
     it('getDetails() - should fetch and return details from database', function(done) {
         model.getDetails(parameter, function(err, document) {
             expect(err).to.be.null;
             expect(document).not.to.be.null;
             expect(document).to.be.an('object');
             done();
         });
     });
 });
```

After running a code coverage report using `istanbul`, my branch coverage score is low because the following block is not covered.

```
if (err) {
    return fn(err, null);
}
```

As I understand, this is a bit of a catch-all for unhandled exceptions, like the database going down, and the like. This error is also designed to bubble-up, so that the app crashes and I could then fix it. How do I write a test case to cover this? Or rather, should I even attempt to cover this?

Comment: Trigger the error in another test case and win.

Comment: How do I trigger the error? Disconnect the DB or something of that sort?

Comment: My opinion is that you should never access the database at all in your unit tests. That being said, you should mock your Model to return an error and expect on that. The mocking could be done using Sinon.js.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mocking library such as [Mockgoose](https://github.com/mccormicka/Mockgoose) to test the error cases - particularly, take a look at the `throwError` option which causes an error to be thrown when a connection is attempted - see [this section](https://github.com/mccormicka/Mockgoose#usage) of the documentation. This should be a separate test case to your above test.

As @limelights said (correctly, in my opinion) in a comment above, it's best to avoid using the real database at all in your unit tests.